# Magicsuggest remove all selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, magicsuggest

How can i remove all selected tags elements in [Jquery Magicsuggest](http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/doc.html)

I used this code, it is not working well

```
$(ms).on('selectionchange', function(e, ms){
      this.removeFromSelection(this.getSelection(), true);
  }
});
```

Note that I also wrote some event functions for (on click, on focus and on blur)  that changes the default class. So how can i attach the new classes to clear the selection, because this function `this.removeFromSelection(this.getSelection(), true);`  seems not working if the class is changed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean with class? Can't see any class selector in your code. Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: you mean the dropdown menu ?? just do -- $(".dropdown-menu").empty()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `$(ms).clear()` or `this.clear()` inside the callback of your code.